# Dynamic title not displaying in POWERBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am new to PowerBI.

I was trying to create a dynamic title for my POWERBI project. I went through some videos. All videos asks me to create measure. I did as the video suggested and the code that I put in was:

```
   Measure = IF(ISCROSSFILTERED('Dash_ER'[County]),"Visted county -" &  FIRSTNONBLANK('Dash_ER'[County],TRUE()), "ER Utilization")
```

I have a Tree map with different counties. When I click on one of the county I want the title to change to - Visited county - 'county name selected' and if none selected I want to print 'ER Utilization' as my title.

I did this but nothing seems to happen. When I drag and drop the measure into the white area  it just displays measure. When I click on ...(three dots) on top the box and clicked on see data. There it display the value that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drag the measure into the white area, Power BI probably defaults to some kind of chart (clustered column chart for me).

[image: Default]

What you need to do is change this to a card by simply clicking on the card visualization while the original visualization is selected. You can then turn off the Category Label of the card if you would like.

[image: Card]

The text of the card will update when you select different items from your tree map.

[image: Results]

For more information, check out this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-dynamic-titles-power-bi-ryan-wade) by Ryan Wade.

Comment: Oh okay.got it! TU

Comment: @yoyoyagami - If my answer has solved your issue, can you please accept it as the answer?

Comment: Sure I will.. .